# Appcelerator Map custom styles

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-modules

Is it possible to customise the map look/style - for example like Uber style with grey and greens? Can it be done using the built in ti.map module?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not possible with `ti.map` right now. For iOS you could use [ti.googlemaps](https://github.com/hansemannn/ti.googlemaps) module that was created by the community which has support for it.

For Android you would need to adjust the `ti.map` module (it is open source on github) to expose this functionality. It is objective-C for iOS or JAVA for Android. Perhaps you could extend the functionality on Ti.Map for iOS too, but that depends if Apple Maps has support for it